# Is there Google Group API to access the post information

Tags: java, google-api, google-groups-api

I was trying to write java program to get all the post information in one google group which I joined in.

Is there any google group API that can help me to achieve my goal?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are no official Google APIs to access the content in groups (only membership data). You could look at options for scraping the data. There are a number of scraping apis out there: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=scraping+google+groups